# Saving a cap sorted by a value

Tags: wireshark, pcap

I have multiple .pcap

But when I drag them into wireshark and click on the timestamp in order to sort it by the timestamp (not the regular time of wireshark, but using another protocol layer that every packet there has) and then exporting specified packets - when I open it again it's not staying sorted...

How can I sort packets by a certain protocol layer and save the pcap sorted while keeping the order in the saved file itself?

Such that if for example the timestamp beforehand was:

1:00
1:25
1:12
1:50
1:30

Then after sorting it in wireshark itself:

1:00
1:12
1:25
1:30
1:50

Then saving it to a file .pcap it would stay the same as after we sorted.

What happens after I click export specified packets as .pcap and drag the new file back to wireshark - it keeps on being disordered.

I also tried using 'reordercap.exe' but it does not get a protocol layer to order it by...

So I assume it ordered by the default "Time" column.

Any help would be appreciated!

Using reordercap
Sorting in the wireshark application itself (clicking twice on te column name)

None would work